# Why do i have to type in my User/Password (of .htaccess/.htpasswd) again and again in Pluginsettings of TYPO3?

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, typo3, .htpasswd, typo3-8.7.x

I protected my TYPO3 Development System with a `.htaccess` file.

At the end of this file i have my passwd-settings

```
AuthName "DEVSERVER BASE"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /-secret.path.to.my.htpasswd-/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Now if i edit the Pluginsettings of my custom Plugin, i have to reenter the User/Pass Combination again and again and again.

Same if i edit a page and add or remove the Relation of a new Resource in Tab **Resources**.

### Someone knows this behaviour, and knows a "fix" to this?

I only want to type my User/Password once.

## Edit

Perhaps this info helps: if i change my Pluginsettings (via Flexform - which i debug in my Controller and in my Fluidtemplate also), i have also type my User/Pass in Frontend again.

## Edit2

TYPO3 Version 8.7.7

## Edit3

The Problem comes with Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)

Comment: I am having the exact same problem (unfortunately no solution so far).

Comment: Look at the Network Tab of your browser console. Are there any 401 responses? The Authentication token is "stored" in the request header until the server responses with a 401. So probably any script/source sends a 401 - which you usually don't really notice.

Comment: Yes there is a 401, but i don't know what this means: `http://null:null@rm8.devserver.ntwickler.de/typo3/index.php?ajaxID=%2Fajax%2Frecord%2Ftree%2FfetchData&ajaxToken=5442fab5f08c7714eefc3332d11ba5a3b441c2aa&tableName=tt_content&fieldName=categories&uid=657&recordTypeValue=list&dataStructureIdentifier=&flexFormSheetName=&flexFormFieldName=&flexFormContainerName=&flexFormContainerIdentifier=&flexFormContainerFieldName=&flexFormSectionContainerIsNew=&command=edit`

Comment: If I were you then I would use https://github.com/sourcebroker/restrictfe instead of .htaccess protection. It has lot of advantages over .htaccess protection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `http://null:null@yourhost` - this represents wrong authentication data and results in a logout. This seems to be a Typo3 bug. There is already a bug entry here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83741

A patch for Typo3 8.7 is under review and can be found here:
https://review.typo3.org/#/c/55559/

**Edit:**

**The Bug has been solved in version 8.7.11**

Comment: It´s actually a Google Chrome bug. The patch for TYPO3 is a workaround. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=808018.

I had the same issue but updated to chrome version 65.0.3325.162 and now the issue is gone.